# What is the MOND elliptical orbit speed equation?

Tags: gravity, orbital-motion, modified-gravity

According to MOND, beyond $~a_0~$, the circular orbit speed is derived with $~v = (GMa_0)^{1/4}~$. That gives a constant orbit speed regardless of radius, as in flat rotation curves.

But accelerations vary in the MOND regime, and an object falling towards the center of the field, or on an elliptical orbit, will have a changing velocity - what is the MOND equivalent of the vis viva equation?

Answer (score 2):

["MOND orbits in the Oort cloud"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.3011) (Lorenzo Iorio) plots MONDian trajectories for a variety of elliptical orbits. The effects vary greatly - some orbits have their eccentricity reduced, some precess while their eccentricity changes. MOND orbits are also "highly sensitive to the initial conditions in the sense that different sets of state vectors yielding the same Keplerian ellipses generate quite different MONDian paths".

Let me also quote [an early critique of MOND by James Felten](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19840010064):

> Simple examples show that a Milgrom acceleration, in the form
> presented so far, imply other far-reaching changes in dynamics. The
> momentum of an isolated system is not conserved, and the usual theorem
> for center-of-mass motion of any system does not hold. Naive
> applications require extreme caution. The model fails to provide a
> complete description of particle dynamics and should be thought of as
> a revision of Kepler's laws rather than Newton's.

Proper theories based on MOND were soon developed, like ["AQUAL"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AQUAL) and ["TeVeS"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor%E2%80%93vector%E2%80%93scalar_gravity). These days there are many ["MOND theories"](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/The_MOND_paradigm_of_modified_dynamics#MOND_theories). I quote Felten because I do not know the extent to which Iorio's calculations are still valid in these more mature MOND theories, especially when many-body effects are taken into account.

Comment: Thank you, I found the Iorio paper, not the Felten one. Neither seems to have an orbit speed equation of the kind I need - basic, and non-circular. Iorio expressed the orbits in a way that I couldn't make use of, I'm looking for just a straightforward equation. It can be similar to the vis viva, though it's a little harder if one needs the semi major axis. Ideally an equivalent of the equation I set out, which derives the speed at one point on an object's trajectory from the speed at another.

Comment: Still looking for an answer, the bounty has not been given out yet.

Comment: Iorio obtained his orbits numerically. If there is a closed form for these MONDian orbits, it may look more like chaos theory than conic sections. But perhaps there are particular regimes in which it simplifies.